# Embed API Working with Custom Components fails to display

Tags: google-analytics, embed

Google Analytics demo code at .

Logged in to Google Chrome as the owner of the Analytics Account and then navigating to that page displays my Google analytics data correctly.

I follow instructions on the page and embed the code into a simple page .

Authentication works as indicated by the displayed message: “You are logged in as: me(at)gmail.com” but there is nothing more, no graph no message.

I am reasonably certain that the page is coded correctly as I have:

- Basic Dashboard (basic.html)
- Multipleviews   (multipleviews.html)and
- Interactive Charts (ic.html)

all working and displaying correctly (they display but not styled like the demo).

Why will the page not display the graphics?

Comment: My links were stripped out by the editor! yoursitename.us is the site url. Google demo site is at ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/custom-components/

Comment: So the page that will not display is at yoursitename.us/cc.html the others mentioned above do display correctly.

Comment: To exclude the obvious problem: the custom components demo requires to to locate the custom components and download them to the directory specified in the code ( in the example that's /public/javascript/embed-api/components/view-selector2.js) - they are not automatically included. Did you do that ? Plus, have a look in your browsers console and see if any errors are displayed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eike pointed out in the comments, you've simply copied and pasted the code from the demo without downloading the components to your own server. If you open up your JavaScript console, you'll notice that you have 404 errors saying the browser can't find those components. Here's a screenshot of what I see on your site:

[image: JavaScript console errors]

To add those components to your site, you have a number of options. I've answered a [similar question](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/issues/92#issuecomment-126755311) on one of the repo's Github issues, but I'll copy it here for convenience.

> The built and minified versions of those components are located in the [`build/javascript/embed-api/components`](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/tree/master/build/javascript/embed-api/components) directory. You can simply download those files and add them as script tags on your page, or include them in your site's main, bundled script.
>
> If you're using an [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) script loader like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), you can also just point to those built files as they're wrapped in a [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) wrapper.
>
> If you're using a tool like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/), you can `npm install` this repo and `require` the files in the [`src/javascript/embed-api/components`](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/tree/master/src/javascript/embed-api/components) directory.